# Is there a more efficient way to handle repetitive functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, frontend

Does anyone know if there is a more efficient way to handle repetitive functions than Cowboy's [Throttle plugin](http://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce)? I've been using it for a while and love it, but in the last few years have any other scripts/ innovations come down the pipe that might handle the task more efficiently?

For reference, an example of a task could be a function that fires on browser resize. Traditionally, I would handle that like so:

```
$(window).resize($.throttle(250, true,
    function() {
        $(window).trigger('onResizeBegin');
    }
));
```

The above limits the number of times the included function fires, etc. I am curious to know if there is an even better way to listen to these type of repetitive checks. In this scenario, maybe a promise for when the browser drag starts / stops, rather than a function constantly checking true / false.

Comment: what exactly is "the task"? running functions no more than once every n ms? the most efficient way will always be natively rather than using a plugin.

Comment: true, but I'm referring to efficiency within jQuery specifically. Updated the question to be more specific.

Comment: What in your case then would be the criteria of "more efficient"

Comment: Basically, until you specify what would make x "more efficient" than y, all we can do is give you opinions based on what we think "more efficient" means (questions resulting in opinionated answers are not allowed here.)

Comment: I don't think a promise would make sense in this scenario, since a promise can only be resolved once. Callbacks are more appropriate.

Comment: efficiency = the reduction of firing a check for a boolean over and over. Is this possible in the code scenario listed above? My question is trying to organize potential non-opinionated ways on how to accomplish that.

Comment: I see two possible ways of looking at this. the `throttle` way where an event is fired no more than once every 250ms, and then the debounce way where an event is fired only when no other events have happened for at least 250ms. Which are you trying to accomplish? Debounce is far easier to code, since all it requires is a variable, setTimeout, and clearTimeout.

Comment: The gut of this question is more about if there is a better solution in general than throttle or debounce. ie not having to constantly fire a check at the DOM at all.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. The "best" solution will depend on the situation and target functionality. In the example you gave, throttle doesn't even make sense because you would want begin resize to tigger immediately and then not again until resizing has stopped.

Comment: I think you approach the problem from the wrong side.
The problem that makes a function inefficient is what is doing inside it.
Running a function 20 other than 100 from my point is not such an improvement. Such functions usually makes changes on the css. Before the change check if the css has the value you want to apply, so that you don't need to apply the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative way to do this

```
$(window).resize($.throttle(250, true,
    function() {
        $(window).trigger('onResizeBegin');
    }
));
```

would be

```
function onResize() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(window).one('resize.throttled', onResize);
  }, 250);
  $(window).trigger('onResizeBegin');
)
$(window).one('resize.throttled', onResize);
```

So that the resize event isn't fired at all during the in-between time.

`.one()` is a jquery thing that makes the event fire only once.

Comment: That sounds a bit like all you did was to inline the `throttle` functionality (and OP's code is much more clear)

Comment: It is very different! OP's version will call the function `function(){/*noop*/}` a few thousand times or whatever. My version will run the event handler *once*.